# express serves index.html even when my routing is to a different file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a public directory with the files `index.html` and `index-08.html` in it.

With the code below, I expect `index-08.html` to be served. But instead, `index.html` gets served with a browser request of `localhost:3000`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/index-08.html');
});
```

But if I change the file name of `index.html` to something else, say `not-index.html`, then the correct file `index-08.html` gets served.

Can you please help me understand why this happens ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because you declared `app.use(express.static)` *before* `app.get('/')`. Express checks routes in the order they are declared, and since `index.html` is a default filename which is used by `static` middleware, it shows `index.html` content.

To fix this you may either put `app.use(express.static)` after `app.get('/')`, or set `index` property of `static` second argument to non-existing file (`false` doesn't seem to work):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {index: '_'}));
```

Comment: did Express 4 change any of this? i'm trying to send a 404 for all HTML page requests and not having much luck. I see no `express.static` anywhere in my code though.

Comment: Agreed. The latest spec for app.use() expects a function as the second param.

Comment: It was my hot reloader for me, but same principle. Any middleware could cause this issue, so if express.static isn't it, check the others.